# Need dropdowns to line up and stay where they are

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a dropdown box by another one, but whenever I hover over one, the other goes to the bottom of the dropdown box.

[Here's what it's like right now.](http://www.jsfiddle.net/myDPb/)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you clean up your code by indenting and separating the CSS block from the HTML on jsFiddle.

Comment: and easier still if you pasted the relevant parts into the question to spare people going over to jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `.sub{ display: inline-block; }` is injecting unnecessary positioning traits.

If you get rid of the display property or set it to `block`, then set `float: left;` instead, you'll get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `vertical-align` property of the elements

```
.sub{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/myDPb/1/)